# Can not filter by '0000000000000' jsonb column

Tags: postgresql-9.5

data is jsonb type

this query work

```
select id, modified_at, data,states from order where  data->'id' = '2100000044078'
```

nice

but this not work

```
select id, modified_at, data,states from shop_order where  data->'id' = '0000000000000'
```

error:

```
LINE 2: ..., data,states from order where  data->'id' = '000000000...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  Token "0000000000000" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: 0000000000000
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 161
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->` returns a `jsonb` value, but you are trying to compare that with a text column. So Postgres tries to convert the value on the right hand side to `jsonb`.

Use the `->>` operator instead which returns the value as `text`

```
where data->>'id' = '0000000000000'
```